# Cypher: How to use FOREACH on an array of objects to create multiple nodes and multiple relationships

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am having trouble with the fetch described in the title of this question. My attempt is the following string:

```
FOREACH (_tabobj IN {_tabarray} |
  MATCH (a:Superlabel),(b)
  WHERE a.id = {_parentid} AND b.id = _tabobj.id
  MERGE (a)-[r:INCLUDES]->(b {
      name    : _tabobj.name
  })
```

I am trying to only create the relationship if it is not already in the database and nothing if the relationship is already in the database. Also trying to only create the b node if it is not already in the database and nothing if the b node is already in the database.

I am very grateful for help you can offer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
MATCH (a:Superlabel {id: {_parentid}})
WITH a, tabarray IN {_tabarray}
UNWIND tabarray AS tabobj
MATCH (b {id: tabobj.id)
MERGE (a)-[r:INCLUDES]->(b {name: tabobj.name})
```

I generally use `FOREACH` as a last resort ;)

And a simpler solution:

```
MATCH (a:Superlabel {id: {_parentid}}), (b)
WHERE b.id IN EXTRACT(tabobj IN {_tabarray} | tabobj.id)
MERGE (a)-[r:INCLUDES]->(b {name: tabobj.name})
```

An important consideration for both of these queries: When matching the `b` node on the `id` property the database index (if you have one) won't be used because indexes are for a label / property pair.  Specifying a label for `b`, if applicable, could help performance.

Comment: For the second example you have, can you reference `tabobj.name` outside EXTRACT like that?

Comment: Ah, good point, thanks! ;)  No, that shouldn't work, I probably just copy/pasted the last line.  I need to head to bed now so I can't look closely, but I suspect that ` {name: tabobj.name}` could just be dropped from that second query